# MYSQL; SUM only to be done if a certain column has a value

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following code

```
$query = "SELECT playerID, name,
  SUM(runs_bowled) / SUM(wickets) AS average
  FROM matchPlayer
  GROUP BY playerID ";
```

BUT this returns a 0 if the person hasn't taken a wicket, what I want is

```
SUM(runs_bowled) / SUM(wickets) AS average
```

to only activate if the SUM(wickets) is greater (or equal) than 10.

Comment: The result set as a whole will have the `average` column. What should it hold for players with less than 10 wickets? Also, you should write `GROUP BY playerID, name` because while MySql does allow you to get away with it, it is meaningless to select a non-grouped column like this query does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs:

```
SELECT 
    playerID, name,
    IF( SUM(wickets) >= 10, SUM(runs_bowled) / SUM(wickets), NULL ) AS average
FROM matchPlayer
GROUP BY playerID
```

Or:

```
SELECT 
    playerID, name,
    SUM(runs_bowled) / SUM(wickets) AS average
FROM matchPlayer
GROUP BY playerID
HAVING SUM(wickets) >= 10
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that :)  the HAVING clause is what it needed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT playerID, name,
 CASE WHEN wickets >= 10 
      THEN runs / wickets
      ELSE 0
 END As Average
FROM (

SELECT
 playerID, name, 
 SUM(runs_bowled) runs, 
 SUM(wickets) wichets
FROM 
 matchPlayer
GROUP BY 
 playerID, name, 
) As A
```